# Different element own some different properties, how to define the `type FieldProps { ... }` in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanna build a form with an object like below:

```js
type FieldProps = {
  label: string;
  value: any;
  type: 'text' | 'select' | 'checkbox' // ...

  // ...
}

type Fieldset = {
  [field: string]: FieldProps
}

const fieldset: Fieldset = {
  userName: {
    type: 'text',
  },
  gender: {
    type: 'select',
    options: { ... }
  },
  tags: {
    element: 'checkbox',
    options: { ... },
    multiple: true,
  }
}

createForm(fieldset);
```

Different elements own some different properties, how to define the `type FieldProps { ... }` in TypeScript ?

Comment: Why not lift the union up from the `type` property to the `FieldProps` type itself as in `type FieldProps = {type: 'text'} | {type: 'select', options: object} | {type: 'checkbox', options: object, multiple: boolean}`?

Comment: Are you talking about built-in `checkbox` / `text` / `radio` attributes here, or do you need some custom props for them?

Comment: The `checkbox` / `text` / `radio` in my code is not built-in component，they are some custom React components

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad，you gave me the answer